# Eliminate highly correlated columns but conserving my non-numerical columns

Tags: r, correlation

I have a data frame with categorical and numerical variables. I want to get rid of the highly correlated variables.

So, first I got rid of all my categorical columns, made the matrix and figured out which numerical columns wort eliminating out. Now I want to go back and also have my categorical-variable columns.

And I'm confused about the simplest way to do it... Maybe a join selecting which columns I want to add from the second table...

```
library(caret)
training_2 <- subset(training, select = -c(user_name ,timestamp, etc))
corr_matrix <- cor(training_2)
highCorr <- findCorrelation(corr_matrix, .75)
training_2<- training_2[,-highCorr]
```

EDIT: DATA

```
structure(list(X = 1:15, yaw_belt = c(-94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, 
-94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, -94.4, 
-94.4, -94.4), gyros_belt_x = c(0, 0.02, 0, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0), gyros_belt_y = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), gyros_belt_z = c(-0.02, 
-0.02, -0.02, -0.03, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 0, -0.02, 
-0.02, 0, -0.02, 0), magnet_belt_x = c(-3L, -7L, -2L, -6L, -6L, 
0L, -4L, -2L, 1L, -3L, -5L, -2L, -3L, -8L, -1L), magnet_belt_y = c(599L, 
608L, 600L, 604L, 600L, 603L, 599L, 603L, 602L, 609L, 596L, 602L, 
606L, 598L, 597L), roll_arm = c(-128, -128, -128, -128, -128, 
-128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -128, -129), 
    pitch_arm = c(22.5, 22.5, 22.5, 22.1, 22.1, 22, 21.9, 21.8, 
    21.7, 21.6, 21.5, 21.5, 21.4, 21.4, 21.4), yaw_arm = c(-161, 
    -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, -161, 
    -161, -161, -161, -161), total_accel_arm = c(34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L
    ), gyros_arm_y = c(0, -0.02, -0.02, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, 
    -0.03, -0.02, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.02, 0, 0), gyros_arm_z = c(-0.02, 
    -0.02, -0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.02, -0.02, 0, 0, -0.02, 
    -0.03, -0.03), magnet_arm_x = c(-368L, -369L, -368L, -372L, 
    -374L, -369L, -373L, -372L, -369L, -376L, -366L, -363L, -372L, 
    -371L, -374L), magnet_arm_z = c(516L, 513L, 513L, 512L, 506L, 
    513L, 509L, 510L, 518L, 516L, 509L, 520L, 509L, 523L, 510L
    ), roll_dumbbell = c(13.05217456, 13.13073959, 12.85074981, 
    13.43119971, 13.37871611, 13.38245941, 13.12694911, 12.75083041, 
    13.15463353, 13.33033728, 13.13073959, 13.10320545, 13.38245941, 
    13.41047767, 13.07948887), pitch_dumbbell = c(-70.49400371, 
    -70.63750507, -70.27811982, -70.39379464, -70.42855971, -70.81758832, 
    -70.24756905, -70.34768359, -70.42520377, -70.85058796, -70.63750507, 
    -70.45974712, -70.81758832, -70.99594236, -70.67116245), 
    yaw_dumbbell = c(-84.87393888, -84.71064711, -85.14078134, 
    -84.87362553, -84.85305745, -84.46500278, -85.09961258, -85.09708174, 
    -84.91563379, -84.44601983, -84.71064711, -84.89472246, -84.46500278, 
    -84.28004856, -84.69053461), total_accel_dumbbell = c(37L, 
    37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
    37L, 37L), gyros_dumbbell_y = c(-0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 
    -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 
    -0.02, -0.02), magnet_dumbbell_z = c(-65, -64, -63, -60, 
    -68, -66, -70, -74, -65, -69, -64, -65, -69, -68, -63), roll_forearm = c(28.4, 
    28.3, 28.3, 28.1, 28, 27.9, 27.9, 27.8, 27.7, 27.7, 27.6, 
    27.5, 27.2, 27.2, 27.2), pitch_forearm = c(-63.9, -63.9, 
    -63.9, -63.9, -63.9, -63.9, -63.9, -63.8, -63.8, -63.8, -63.8, 
    -63.8, -63.9, -63.9, -63.9), yaw_forearm = c(-153, -153, 
    -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, -152, 
    -151, -151, -151), total_accel_forearm = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 
    36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L
    ), gyros_forearm_x = c(0.03, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
    0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0), gyros_forearm_z = c(-0.02, 
    -0.02, 0, 0, -0.02, -0.03, -0.02, 0, -0.02, -0.02, -0.02, 
    -0.03, -0.03, -0.03, -0.02), accel_forearm_x = c(192L, 192L, 
    196L, 189L, 189L, 193L, 195L, 193L, 193L, 190L, 193L, 191L, 
    193L, 193L, 192L), accel_forearm_z = c(-215L, -216L, -213L, 
    -214L, -214L, -215L, -215L, -213L, -214L, -215L, -214L, -215L, 
    -215L, -214L, -214L), magnet_forearm_x = c(-17L, -18L, -18L, 
    -16L, -17L, -9L, -18L, -9L, -16L, -22L, -17L, -11L, -15L, 
    -14L, -16L), magnet_forearm_y = c(654, 661, 658, 658, 655, 
    660, 659, 660, 653, 656, 657, 657, 655, 659, 656), magnet_forearm_z = c(476, 
    473, 469, 469, 473, 478, 470, 474, 476, 473, 465, 478, 472, 
    478, 472)), .Names = c("X", "yaw_belt", "gyros_belt_x", "gyros_belt_y", 
"gyros_belt_z", "magnet_belt_x", "magnet_belt_y", "roll_arm", 
"pitch_arm", "yaw_arm", "total_accel_arm", "gyros_arm_y", "gyros_arm_z", 
"magnet_arm_x", "magnet_arm_z", "roll_dumbbell", "pitch_dumbbell", 
"yaw_dumbbell", "total_accel_dumbbell", "gyros_dumbbell_y", "magnet_dumbbell_z", 
"roll_forearm", "pitch_forearm", "yaw_forearm", "total_accel_forearm", 
"gyros_forearm_x", "gyros_forearm_z", "accel_forearm_x", "accel_forearm_z", 
"magnet_forearm_x", "magnet_forearm_y", "magnet_forearm_z"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some of the data of `training_2`? Use `dput(training_2)` to edit your question (or `dput(head(training_2,15))` if the data is big).

Comment: Don't you want to find correlation between categorical variables as well ?

Comment: @LyzandeR Ok, some data added.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Uhm, I haven't thought of it. There is a classification variable which tells me which category each row belongs to, one that tells me which person belongs the data to, and a timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to use your data unfortunately @mclzc because one of the columns only has one value and it returns an error when I try to calculate the correlations, but I ll provide a sample data set.

```
library(caret)
#sample data, 4 numeric fields and 2 categorical
df <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=runif(10), c=1:10, d=1:10, e=letters[1:10], f=letters[1:10])

#categorical columns
cat_cols <- c('e', 'f')
#remove categorical
df2 <- df[!names(df) %in% cat_cols]

#run correlations
cor_mat <- cor(df2)

#the index of the columns to be removed because they have a high correlation
index <- findCorrelation(cor_mat, .75)

#the name of the columns chosen above
to_be_removed <- colnames(cor_mat)[index]

#now go back to df and use to_be_removed to subset the original df
df[!names(df) %in% to_be_removed]
```

Output (only column c is removed as instructed by findCorrelations, whereas categorical columns e and f are still preserved):

```
           a          b  d e f
1  0.8495639 0.52388246  1 a a
2  0.9478409 0.11466655  2 b b
3  0.9086955 0.12097760  3 c c
4  0.7724303 0.03160203  4 d d
5  0.1269406 0.10740182  5 e e
6  0.7454943 0.95892265  6 f f
7  0.2651961 0.15223472  7 g g
8  0.5714763 0.49808509  8 h h
9  0.1226760 0.06088693  9 i i
10 0.5526266 0.14715471 10 j j
```

Notice above that the `findCorrelation` function returns the index of the column to be removed but not the name. You need to have the name so that you can exclude that from the original data set (you cannot use the index as the number of columns changed after excluding the categorical columns). So, in my code above, I used the `index` to find the column name and then used this to remove the unneeded column (preserving the categorical columns)

Comment: Thank you so much LyzandeR! Now I can continue and work on with your tidy approach!

Comment: You are very welcome @mclzc :). Glad I could be of help.